# Google UserId and Password validation from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have to authenticate a user based on his google account.

I don't have any user authentication database from asp.net.

Is there any service available from Google which accepts google email id and Password in turn, it will check the given user is valid or not.

I tried OAUTH2 but no where it is accepting emailid and password from client side.

Am i missing anything ? and How can i fix this ??

Comment: In a new MVC project, there is an `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs`, with a commented-out `app.UseGoogleAuthentication();`. Apparently just uncommenting that is enough to use Google Auth. (Never used it myself, though)

Comment: please show ... what you did till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below links :-

1) http://loginwithgoogle.codeplex.com/

2) http://dotnetopenauth.net/  This is implemented in ASP.NET and It includes samples for Google logins, and it's very easy.

Comment: I totally overlooked the codeplex option. It helped.